# Can not get correct previous and next rows in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am new to this forum and new to SQL. Can you please help me with the foloowing:

I have a table with all transactions. I want to find each transaction's Start date and End date with respect to Transaction_By(i.e., User).

[My table and results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60zGO.jpg)

I tried using the below query but not giving the correct results.

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1OVq.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Hi,
Sorry, I am totally new to this forum, so not sure how to add image for my second query. Please find my new query data and expected results here.

[My new query data and expected results are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhTgV.jpg)

Thanks once again.

Hi Andrei,
Please find my new data along with my expected results here.

New data link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e49b/1/0

Expected results:[My new data's expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U50yI.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do not put image of codes, but put the codes directly.

Comment: Sorry, please find my code as below:

Comment: WITH CTE_ALL_TRNS AS 
      (
 SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANS_NO, TRANS_BY ORDER BY TRANS_DATE ASC) ROWNUM1,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANS_NO, TRANS_BY ORDER BY TRANS_DATE DESC) ROWNUM2,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TRANS_NO, TRANS_BY ORDER BY TRANS_DATE ASC) AS DENSE1,
  CASE WHEN Transaction = 'Processed' 
     THEN 2
       ELSE 1
  END AS VAL1
  FROM MY_TABLE
 
       )

Comment: SELECT CUR.TRANS_NO,
 CUR.TRANS_BY,
 CASE WHEN CUR.DENSE1 = 1 AND CUR.Transaction = 'Processed'
    THEN CUR.Start_Date
      WHEN CUR.VAL1 = 2 AND CUR.ROWNUM2 = 1 
    THEN PREV.Trans_Date
      ELSE PREV.Trans_Date
 END AS Trans_Start_Date,
 CASE WHEN CUR.DENSE1 = 1 AND CUR.Transaction = 'Processed'
    THEN 'Initiated'
      WHEN CUR.VAL1 = 2 AND CUR.ROWNUM2 = 1
    THEN PREV.Transaction
      ELSE PREV.Transaction 
 END AS Transaction_Start,
 CUR.Trans_Date AS Trans_End_Date,
 CUR.Transaction AS Transaction_End 
FROM CTE_ALL_TRNS CUR

Comment: LEFT JOIN CTE_ALL_TRNS PREV ON PREV.ROWNUM2 = CUR.ROWNUM1 - 1 
ORDER BY 1, 3;

Comment: Please edit your question and put those codes in it.

Comment: Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please find my code is here :    [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ff407/1/0]

Comment: Please [edit] all new information direction into the question. You want to make it as easy as possible for people to provide you with assistance, and having to read all that in the comments is not easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SQL Server 2008 does not support [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016)/[LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) functions, try this:

```
SELECT
  c.Trans_No, c.Trans_By,
  COALESCE(p.Trans_Date, c.Start_Date) AS Trans_Start_Date,
  COALESCE(p.Transact, 'Initiated') AS Transaction_Start,
  c.Trans_Date AS Trans_End_Date, c.Transact AS Transaction_End
FROM My_table AS c
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP(1) *
  FROM My_table AS p
  WHERE p.Trans_No = c.Trans_No AND p.Trans_Date < c.Trans_Date
  ORDER BY p.Trans_No, p.Trans_Date DESC
) AS p
ORDER BY Trans_No, Trans_Start_Date;
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| Trans_No | Trans_By | Trans_Start_Date | Transaction_Start | Trans_End_Date | Transaction_End |
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
|      101 | Smith    | 2019-01-02       | Initiated         | 2019-01-03     | Processed       |
|      101 | Mary     | 2019-01-03       | Processed         | 2019-01-06     | Finalised       |
|      102 | Donald   | 2019-01-09       | Initiated         | 2019-01-10     | Processed       |
|      102 | Tony     | 2019-01-10       | Processed         | 2019-01-11     | Rejected        |
|      102 | Jennifer | 2019-01-11       | Rejected          | 2019-01-13     | Corrected       |
|      102 | George   | 2019-01-13       | Corrected         | 2019-01-17     | Finalised       |
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e467c/15).

**Update:**

```
WITH
  a AS (
    SELECT
      c.Trans_No, c.Trans_By, p.Trans_By AS Prev_Trans_By,
      COALESCE(p.Trans_Date, c.Start_Date) AS Trans_Start_Date,
      ca.pad + COALESCE(p.Transact, 'Initiated') AS Trans_Start,
      c.Trans_Date AS Trans_End_Date,
      ca.pad + c.Transact AS Trans_End
    FROM My_table AS c
    CROSS APPLY (
      VALUES(STR(DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, c.Trans_Date), 5))
    ) AS ca(pad)
    OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP(1) *
      FROM My_table AS p
      WHERE p.Trans_No = c.Trans_No AND p.Trans_Date < c.Trans_Date
      ORDER BY p.Trans_No, p.Trans_Date DESC
    ) AS p
  )
SELECT
  a.Trans_No,
  a.Trans_By,
  MIN(a.Trans_Start_Date) AS Trans_Start_Date,
  RIGHT(MIN(a.Trans_Start),
        LEN(MIN(a.Trans_Start)) - 5) AS Trans_Start,
  MAX(a.Trans_End_Date) AS Trans_End_Date,
  RIGHT(MAX(a.Trans_End), LEN(MAX(a.Trans_End)) - 5) AS Trans_End
FROM a
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT
    SUM(CASE
          WHEN s.Prev_Trans_By IS NULL OR
               s.Prev_Trans_By != s.Trans_By THEN 1
          ELSE 0
        END)
  FROM a AS s
  WHERE s.Trans_No = a.Trans_No AND
        s.Trans_Start_Date <= a.Trans_Start_Date
) AS ca(g)
GROUP BY a.Trans_No, a.Trans_By, ca.g
ORDER BY Trans_No, Trans_Start_Date;
```

**Output:**

```
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
| Trans_No | Trans_By | Trans_Start_Date | Trans_Start | Trans_End_Date | Trans_End |
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
|      101 | Smith    | 2019-01-02       | Initiated   | 2019-01-03     | Processed |
|      101 | Mary     | 2019-01-03       | Processed   | 2019-01-06     | Finalised |
|      102 | Donald   | 2019-01-09       | Initiated   | 2019-01-10     | Processed |
|      102 | Tony     | 2019-01-10       | Processed   | 2019-01-11     | Rejected  |
|      102 | Jennifer | 2019-01-11       | Rejected    | 2019-01-13     | Corrected |
|      102 | George   | 2019-01-13       | Corrected   | 2019-01-17     | Finalised |
|      105 | Tony     | 2019-03-01       | Initiated   | 2019-03-05     | Corrected |
|      105 | Smith    | 2019-03-05       | Corrected   | 2019-03-07     | Corrected |
|      105 | Jennifer | 2019-03-07       | Corrected   | 2019-03-08     | Finalised |
+----------+----------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

Test it online with [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5f3fb/87).

Comment: Sorry to ask once again. 

For a similar scenario (it is bit different, where the Transaction_Start will be reset to Trans_date when Transact = Failed/Finalised), I have written a similar code . But my code is not working. Could you please advice where i am doing wrong. My data and my code are as below:
 sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64c42/6 

Thanks once again.

Comment: Please show the desired result for the data presented on sqlfiddle.com/#!18/64c42/6.

Comment: Please find my data and my expected results here:    [link] (img src="file:///F:/My%20new%20query%20and%20result.htm">)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to add an image in the comments section. So added my new data and expected results image at the top. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrei. All the details are coming correctly except Trans_By.

Comment: Many thanks for your solution Andrei. It worked well.

Comment: Hi Andrei, The first solution(for my first question, that I asked for the first time) is failing if the Trans_by is repeated in the next row. Can you please look into it. Please find my link here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fd083/1/0

Comment: What result do you expect to get?

Comment: Hi Andrei, Please find my new data (in a link) along with my expected results image are at the top. Thanks once again.

Comment: I have modified the query a little bit and it's all sorted out now. Many thanks for your help and guidance.

Comment: @pams, i added my answer.

Comment: Once again thanks Andrei for your solution. SUM () Over is not working in SQL Server 2008. But I could solved the issue with similar way of your code with few CTEs. As a SQL beginner I really learnt a lot from your solutions. Hope you continue help others like me. And once again, thanks for your patience, help and guidance.

Comment: @pams, you're right. It's my fault. But SQL Server 2008 is a story from the distant past :)